# Difference between subscript [] operator and push_back method for inserting charachter in a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am stuck on this stupid doubt and can't understand which part have I understood wrong.
I am trying to fill an empty string and I thought of doing it using the subscipt `[]` operator but found that although loop runs perfectly but the final string is still empty with size zero. However `push_back` runs perfectly fine. I can use `push_back` but want to understand the reason for the first one. If anyone can clarify?

```
string r;
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
     r[i] = 'a';
}
cout << r.size();    //output: 0
cout << endl;

for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    r.push_back('a');
}
cout << r.size();    //output: 5
```

Comment: Your first for-loop is undefined behavior.  You can't assign a char at an index >= to the string's length.  The string `r` is initially empty and hence has 0 length.

Comment: `push_back` adds a new element to the string. `[]` is used to access an existing element, so doesn't work when the string is empty.

Comment: `[]` doesn't add anything to a `string`. It just writes over whatever was already there. If there wasn't anything there... That's bad.

Comment: Use `r.at(i)` instead of `r[i]` to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: But when I access ```r[0]```, I get the correct output. Shouldn't I get garbage?

Comment: There is no good way to predict what you'll get.  Some libraries add extra checks into the debug version of the library and make the problem easier to find by spitting out an error message and then aborting the program. `r[0]` could hold exactly what you wrote because you got unlucky and managed to hit a writeable location. But you could find some time later that you wrote over some other variable and now the program crashes somewhere completely unrelated. Those can be a <expletive deleted> to untangle. You can't count on anything recognizable in the general sense.

Comment: *Shouldn't I get garbage?* -- Maybe the output *is* garbage, and it so happens it is equal to what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as it is for `std::vector`, `std::string` doesn't have bounds check when using subscript operator. When creating empty string, you have a container of zero length, thus when you assign values by index, the values are assigned to memory out of the collection's bounds

Comment: What are you trying to get at with *As simple as it is for std::vector, std::string doesn't have bounds check when using subscript operator.*?  `std::vector` doesn't do bounds checks either in the subscript operator.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm just saying that it works the same way. Just treat `std::string` a special kind of a collection, which acts like `std::vector` in this case

Comment: But while accessing, it gives correct value which was stored. Shouldn't there be a garbage value from memory?

Comment: @Mohd.Anas first of all it's undefined behaviour. I.e. it won't be consistent between different version of compilers (or even between different runs with the same compiler). In your case i can't see how you read the data, but I assume the compiler just writes the data you give to the memory which does not belong to the string, so it means it may change at any point during runtime later on

Comment: *Shouldn't there be a garbage value* -- What is a "garbage value"?  0?  1?  2? -- They are all "garbage values" if you access a vector out-of-bounds.  Just because the values look "simple" doesn't mean they are not garbage.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Actually I was getting the same value which I tried to store, that's why I got confused.